# Loop to get value of object based on key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a large object:

```
var json = {
    "userRole": "Admin",
    "assetDtlsList": [{
        "machineId": "1A",
        "serialNo": "123",
        "lon": "-78.80472",
        "totalFuel": "685.3"
    },{
        "machineId": "2A",
        "serialNo": "123",
        "lon": "-78.80472",
        "totalFuel": "685.3"    
    },{
        "machineId": "3A",
        "serialNo": "123",
        "lon": "-78.80472",
        "totalFuel": "685.3"
    }],
    "count": 0
}
```

Now i want to get all the "machineId" in a array

I tried :

```
$.each(json, function (key, data) {
    console.log(key)
    $.each(data, function (index, data) {
        console.log(data.machineId)
        // push data to array
    })
})
```

but not working?

please help!

Comment: Note that your object is invalid - should `assetDtlsList` be an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you correct your object's syntax:

```
var json = {
    "userRole": "Admin",
    "assetDtlsList": [{
        "machineId": "1A",
        "serialNo": "123",
        "lon": "-78.80472",
        "totalFuel": "685.3"
    },{
        "machineId": "2A",
        "serialNo": "123",
        "lon": "-78.80472",
        "totalFuel": "685.3"    
    },{
        "machineId": "3A",
        "serialNo": "123",
        "lon": "-78.80472",
        "totalFuel": "685.3"
    }],
    "count": 0
}
```

You can create an array of the `machineId` properties with a simple loop:

```
var machineIds = [];
$.each(json.assetDtlsList, function(i, obj) {
    machineIds.push(obj.machineId);
});

console.log(machineIds); // = [ "1A", "2A", "3A" ]
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5fk5x8ud/)

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is invalid. the valid json is:

```
{
    "userRole": "Admin",
    "assetDtlsList": [ //Missing bracket
        {
            "machineId": "1A", // Missing quotes
            "serialNo": "123",
            "lon": "-78.80472",
            "totalFuel": "685.3"
        },
        {
            "machineId": "2A", // Missing quotes
            "serialNo": "123",
            "lon": "-78.80472",
            "totalFuel": "685.3"
        },
        {
            "machineId": "3A", // Missing quotes
            "serialNo": "123",
            "lon": "-78.80472",
            "totalFuel": "685.3"
        }
    ],
    "count": 0
}
```

Now use this code to get machine id:

```
$.each(abc.assetDtlsList, function (key, data) {
    console.log(data.machineId);
});
```

Edit: To push the properties to array, Use this code:

```
var mIDs = []; 
$.each(abc.assetDtlsList, function (key, data) {
      mIDs.push(data.machineId);
});
```

Comment: You've corrected the object's syntax but not actually answered the question.

Comment: Updated the code for correct json and accessing machineId

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var machineIds = json.assetDtlsList.map(function (el) {
  return el.machineId;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrukcofu/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```js
var temp = [];
$.each(json,function(row,val){
 if(typeof val ==  "object"){
  $.each(val,function(r,v){
   if(v.machineId)
    temp.push(v.machineId);
  });
 }
})
```

Comment: Snippets should be used for working code. Along with that I recommend you explain what this code is doing, it may not be clear to the OP.